# Struts2 jQuery plugin topic for succefully loaded Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

I want to call an function in my jsp pages every time the page is successfully
loaded via Ajax call.
Consider below:

```
|Main.jsp--------------------------------------|
|         Link A    Link B    Link C           |
|                                              |
|         -<div id="content">----------        |
|         |                           |        |
|         |                           |        |
|         |                           |        |
|         |                           |        |
|         ----------------------</div>-        |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Each of the links will invoke LinkA.jsp, LinkB.jsp and LinkC.jsp
And the links are as below:

```
<sj:a href="%{urlA}" targets="content">LinkA</sj:a>
<sj:a href="%{UrlB}" targets="content">LinkB</sj:a>
```

There are common javascript functions which must be called when the jsp files are loaded. I can write these general files in  an initial.js and add it to all jsp pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="initial.js" />"></script>
```

All the jsp files contains a form and I want to manipulate a common function on all inputs some thing like below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("input").changeEncodingInput();
});
```

If I add this code in Main.jsp, the `changeEncodingInput` will not apply when I load LinkB.jsp and LinkC.jsp

But I think there must be better way.

I am looking for a adding the initial.js file to Main.jsp and do not repeat it in every page.

It seems that the struts 2 jquery plugin internally manage the Ajax events. May be topics are published internally and we can subscribe to it?

Any ideas?!

Comment: So why don't you add your script to main.jsp?

Comment: @AleksandrM I have updated the question. Please review. The problem is that there is a common function that needs to be applied to all inputs in all jsp files, but when I add it to main.jsp, the function will not apply to newly loaded jsp files.

Comment: So there is no event published so I can subscriber to! Can you describe what event should I used with On. I found ajaxStop function which may helpful for me, what do you think!

Comment: What is `changeEncodingInput`?

Comment: This function changes the encoding of numbers so when user clicks 1 it will convert it to ۱ and 2 to ۲ . I also across many other common functions which might need to be manipulates on forms. Although these forms are in different jsp files they are all loaded via AJax in the body of main.jsp. Some how they are are child pags of main.jsp. And I hope to find best way to manage the common functions of these child in the parent.

Comment: Then you should just call again your `changeEncodingInput` on successful sub-page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reviews I found the best solution could be achived by adding below to the main.jsp.
I hoped that the framework published an event but I could not find any, hope the framework will support that later!

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("input[lang='fa']").changeEncodingInput();
});
```

Thanks to @Aleksandr for comments !